# Can uiautomator2 support the display and control of multiple screens on a device

Tags: ui-automation, android-uiautomator, uiautomatorviewer

uiautomator2 support one screen for one device,Currently, we hope to be able to display and control multiple screens of the same device simultaneously
See that the bottom layer is the default display。
uiautomator2 support the display and control of multiple screens on a device?
Do you have any suggestions? For uiautomator2 adapting to multiple screens on one device